# how can my mockito mock call the original method with changed params?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using a mockito mock.

I want to control the invocation of method `foo(String a, Date b)`

to call the original method with `foo(a, fixed_date)`

How can I use mockito API to do so?

```
MyObject myObject = mock(MyObject.class);

        when(myObject.foo(anyString, any(Date.class))
                .thenCallRealMethod();
```

why this doesn't work?

It never redirects the call

```
ImagesSorter imagesSorter = spy(new ImagesSorter());
        doReturn(imagesSorter.sortImages(images, user, fakeNowDate)).when(imagesSorter).sortImages(images,user);
```

Comment: What's the implementation of the method `thenCallRealMethod()`? Which class implements this method?

Comment: `thenCallRealMethod()` is actually part of mockito API

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Your test is now executing code differently than it will at deployment. Are you doing this because your test scenario is written for a specific date instance?

Comment: I find this idea a bit unsettling for a test. Why would one ever want that. The behavior is the one of a partial mock and it's globally a bad bad idea.

Comment: In your last piece of code with `ImageSorter`, the value from `doReturn` will be returned only when the spy is called with the same `images` and `user` arguments.

Comment: yes. that's what I meant to do. can you please view my revised question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138436/how-to-use-mockito-spy-to-redirect-a-method-call

Comment: It can be necessary if find yourself needing to mock one artifact returned by a factory but nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, but it's a little hacky, let's assume the return type for `foo` is `String`:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;

...

final Date fixedDate = ...;

MyClass myObject = mock(MyClass.class);

when(myObject.foo(anyString(), any(Date.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            // Switch the 2nd argument
            invocation.getArguments()[1] = fixedDate;
            // Then call the real method
            return (String) invocation.callRealMethod();
        }
    });
```

With `MyClass` being for example:

```
public class MyClass {

    public String foo(String s, Date d) {
        return s + d;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your last example with `ImageSorter`, i think you don't need Mockito, a simple decorator would do the trick:

```
public interface ImageSorter {
    void sortImages(Images images, User user);

    void sortImages(Images images, User user, Date date);
}

public class ImageSorterDecorator implements ImageSorter {

    final ImageSorter delegate;
    final Date fixedDate;

    public ImageSorterDecorator (ImageSorter delegate, Date fixedDate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.fixedDate = fixedDate;
    }

    public void sortImages(Images images, User user){
        delegate.sortImages(images, user, fixedDate);
    }

    public void sortImages(Images images, User user, Date date){
        delegate.sortImages(images, user, fixedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? It uses mockito API, i'm using version 1.9.5

Comment: Sorry, a closing parenthesis was missing after `any(Date.class)`. I fixed it